# How to use monit to make sure only one instance of process is running

Tags: monitoring, ruby, daemon, monit

I have ruby daemons running.  Once in a while we'll accidentally start up a second instance of it, which causes race conditions.

Can I use Monit to detect if multiple instances of 'my_ruby_daemon' is running? And if so kill the extra instance?

Comment: Good question... I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can do this with `monit`, but it strikes me as the **Wrong Solution** which may bring up its own problems (especially if Bad Things happen if you kill the "wrong" daemon (?)).

The **Right Solution** is to have your daemon create and check a lock (PID files work great for this -- if `mydaemon.pid` exists and the PID in it is alive refuse to start the daemon).
There are several ruby lockfile gems/libraries/etc available ([like this one](https://github.com/lisa/ruby-lockfile)).
If modifying the daemon is out of the question almost every Unix system comes with the `lockfile` command or something similar -- wrap the daemon in a shell script that creates/checks the lock before attempting to start.

It helps if you put the lock file somewhere that gets cleared on reboot (`/tmp`, `/var/run`, etc.) so that if your system crashes the daemon will restart when its init script runs.